# Popup Modal Textarea Value

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, popup

I'm using JSP I want to display a value in the popup modal text area but the value I need is in a text file in my local storage I Read the file using java but it's not displaying the value inside the text area while the popup appears.

[No Value in Text Area in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmaK4.png)

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="7" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openpopup"></textarea><br>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="openpopup" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <textarea rows="7" name="NewContent">
                                        <%
                                        while(myfile.hasNextLine())
                                        {
                                        out.println(myfile.nextLine());
                                        }
                                        %>
                                    </textarea>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <input type="submit" value="ADD"  formaction="HomeNote.jsp">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, add your code as text not image .

Comment: I've Added the Code @swati Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure this `out.println(myfile.nextLine());` is showing value ? Why not first try printing simply text i.e : `<% out.println("printed,,,"); %>`  and see if that works .

Comment: Yes I Already checked the simple out statement but whatever java code is inside text area is not working Because it is a popup. @swati